# Primefaces Client Side Validation on Server Side

Tags: primefaces, client-side-validation

I'm using Primefaces Client Side Validation with AJAX for better responsiveness.
It is critical that the data is validated on the server side as well to ensure that the client has not hacked the front-end.
Will Primefaces check the data on the server-side as well?

Answer (score 1):

Client Side validation is client side validation. Server side validation is server side validation. So the client side validadation will never run on the server side... But...

In [the client side validation showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/basic.xhtml) it even states

> Compatible with Server Side Implementation.

And in the [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/basic.xhtml) it states it even stronger.

Since they use the same annotations (as you can see from the examples in the primefaces showcase and read in the documentation) and it nowhere states that server side validation is disabled when enabling client side validation, the answer is: yes

Comment: Primefaces forum seems to suggest differently: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=42308

Comment: No, it says the same only in different words